# Hibernate error only when deploying grails application on Tomcat 7 server

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, grails, groovy, spring-security

I've developed a grails 2.3.5 application which works completely on localhost, but when deploying to my Tomcat 7 server, I get following error:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error

  URI
/schedulingAPI-0.1/tests
  Class
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException
  Message
Cannot cast object 'org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@5ac08512' with class 'org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl' to class 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.SessionFactoryProxy'
```

Trace:

```
    Line | Method
->>   12 | $tt__parseXML      in mp.ra.SchedulingService
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     21 | $tt__index         in mp.ra.TestController
|    200 | doFilter . . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter           in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     88 | processFilterChain in com.odobo.grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter
|     66 | doFilter           in     ''
|     53 | doFilter . . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|    108 | doFilter           in com.odobo.grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter
|     49 | doFilter . . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|     82 | doFilter           in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|     66 | doFilter . . . . . in com.odobo.grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestLogoutFilter
|     82 | doFilter           in com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

The only clue I have is that this has something to do with the springsecurity plugin.

**EDIT:**
This is code fragemtn in my mp.ra.SchedulingService where the error occurs:

```
def parseXML() {
    LessonParser par = new LessonParser(sessionFactory:sessionFactory)
    //par.parse(["src/data/tweede/"])
    par.parse(["src/data/access/","src/data/tweede/"])
}
```

This is my LessonParser class:

```
package mp.data.parser


import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser
import groovy.io.FileType
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
import mp.ra.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.SessionFactoryProxy
import org.xml.sax.InputSource

class LessonParser {

    SessionFactoryProxy sessionFactory

    public void parse(baseFileLocations){

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        //alle directories overlopen
        baseFileLocations.each(){ location ->
            def dir = new File(location)

            //alle bestanden van directory inlezen
            dir.eachFile(){ file ->

                if (file.name.endsWith(".xml")) {
//                  print file.name
                    //alle bestanden parsen
                    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
                    InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
                    is.setEncoding("UTF-8")

                    LessonHandler handler = new LessonHandler(sessionFactory)

                    saxParser.parse(is, handler);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I used SesionFactory is to reduce the time during which the XML files are read. Without the use of SessionFactory this took approximately 20 min whereas with SessionFactory a couple of minutes.

Comment: Look at line 12 of mp.ra.SchedulingService or post the source for that class. For completeness you may want to also post the relevant action/method from the Controller as well.

Comment: In your service method of parseXML how is sessionFactory being set/injected?

Comment: just a few condierations: does it work if you use just "def sessionFactory"? often these errors already show up when you run locally with ``run-war`` (instead of ``run-app``) - might save you time and makes debugging easier.